# Fontaine-Mazur for GL_1

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties, galois-representations, nt.number-theory

For any number field $K$, the Fontaine-Mazur conjecture predicts that any potentially semistable $p$-adic representation of the absolute Galois group $G_K$ of $K$ that is almost everywhere unramified comes from algebraic geometry (i.e., is a subquotient of the etale cohomology of some variety over $K$, up to Tate twist). As far as I can see, the only cases where any progress has been made concerns the case that $K$ is totally real or CM.

This made me wonder: Is the Fontaine-Mazur conjecture known to be true for $1$-dimensional representations for any number field $K$? For CM fields, the theory of CM abelian varieties gives varieties whose cohomology realizes nontrivial characters (and I guess that easy variations should produce all characters). What are the geometric objects appearing for other fields?

[edit: The word 'geometric' is avoided now, see the comments.]

Comment: I thought Fontaine and Mazur *defined* a $p$-adic representaion of $G_K$ to be geometric if it is almost everywhere unramified and potentially semistable (at every place $\mathfrak{p}|p$ of $K$), and conjectured that every geometric representation is ... 

Comment: ... for example modular if moreover it is odd and $K={\bf Q}$

Comment: The terminology used in Fontaine and Mazur's paper is that "geometric" means "almost everywhere unramified and potentially semistable at places |p" and an irreducible p-adic Galois representation is said to "come from algebraic geometry" if it is isomorphic (up to Tate twist) to a subquotient of the etale cohomology of an algebraic variety. Their conjecture is then that an irreducible p-adic rep comes from algebraic geometry if and only if it is geometric.

Comment: Oh and I guess the proposition in section 6 of Fontaine-Mazur is relevant to the question?

Comment: Congratulations!(about the Clay.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Let $\chi$ be a one-dimensional geometric (in the sense of FM) $p$-adic Galois representation of $G_K$ and let $\psi$ be the Hecke character of $K$ associated to $\chi$ by class field theory. The fact that $\chi$ is de Rham (=pst) at all primes above $p$ imples that $\psi$ is an *algebraic* Hecke character. Generally, the only algebraic Hecke characters of $K$ are of the form $(\text{finite order})\cdot\mathcal{N}^n$ where $\mathcal{N}$ is the norm character. Under class field theory, $\mathcal{N}$ corresponds to the cyclotomic character, so it comes from geometry; additionally, any finite order character comes from geometry (it arises as the subquotient of the $H^0$ of a zero-dimensional variety). The only time there are more algebraic Hecke characters is when $K$ contains a CM field. Denoting $L$ the maximal CM field in $K$, every algebraic Hecke character of $K$ is of the form $(\text{finite order})\cdot(\psi_L\circ\mathcal{N}_{K/L})$ where $\psi_L$ is an algebraic Hecke character of $L$ and $\mathcal{N}_{K/L}$ is the norm from $K$ to $L$. Again, finite order characters come from geometry, so this case is reduced to the CM case. As you've mentioned the CM case has been dealt with, so Fontaine–Mazur is true for $\mathrm{GL}(1)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I wasn't aware that algebraic characters have this special form.

Comment: Rob, should mention refs, such as Ch. III (esp. App. A) in Serre's book on abelian $\ell$-adic repn's, for why pst (or HT) at $p$-adic places implies global algebraicity up to finite-order, with finite-order part coming from ramification away from $p$ (finite, by global CFT) and finiteness of Hilbert class fields. Main Thm of CM relates Tate mods of CM abelian var. to certain alg. Hecke characters factoring through reflex norm of a CM type, but to conversely relate *all* alg. Hecke characters to CM abelian varieties is totally not obvious (& there's no "modern" published ref.), right? 

Comment: "but to conversely relate all alg. Hecke characters to CM abelian varieties is totally not obvious (& there's no "modern" published ref.), right?"
$$ $$
Do you just mean Casselman's theorem as in Shimura's paper? That is, Theorem 6 of http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970768
$$ $$
Maybe section 4 of chapter 1 of Schappacher is also of interest, for it deals with motives. http://www.springer.com/mathematics/numbers/book/978-3-540-18915-2 

Comment: Dear Junkie: I had in mind Casselman's thm (though I didn't know such a result was proved by Casselman, and unfortunately I find Shimura's writing hard to unravel...pre-modern to me), but it doesn't fit what Rob H. said since it entails some extra hypotheses on the alg. Hecke character whereas Rob H. he makes a statement on the structure of *all* algebraic Hecke characters which I had not heard before.  So I wanted to know if Rob H. has a "modern" reference to justify what he said. The Schappacher reference seems more suitable (ultimately relying on Casselman's thm); thanks. 

Comment: OK, I see the problem now. I can add that, At the bottom of section 1 of chapter 1, Schappacher also emphasizes "all" when he says
$$ $$
In order to find "geometric" objects over $K$ whose $L$-functions include ALL $L$-functions of algebraic Hecke characters of $K$ we have to pass from abelian varieties (with complex multiplication) to motives.


Comment: Quick comment (more later): I didn't mean to imply the CM case was easy to handle or had been, I just wanted to reduce to the CM case. My reading of the question hadn't noticed the parenthetical emphasizing the fact that the OP didn't know how to deal with ALL CM  alg Hecke characters. I would've guessed that either "Motifs et groupes de Taniyama" in Deligne–Milne–Ogus–Shih" or Blasius' 1986 article "On the critical values of Hecke L-series" would address the question of obtaining all algebraic Hecke characters over a CM field, though perhaps neither makes sure they get ALL Hecke characters.

Comment: Blasius does the CM case of Deligne's conjecture, and Harder/Schappacher (Section 5) then show this for all Hecke L-functions of totally imaginary fields (not just CM fields) using this. Siegel (as noted by Serre in an Annals paper of Coates/Lichtenbaum) did the totally real case, and the other cases are trivial. Not exactly Fontaine/Mazur, but....
$$ $$
Harder/Schappacher http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BFb0084583
$$ $$
Goldstein and Schappacher (Crelle paper) had already done this in many cases, essentially following the Damerell methods as developed by Weil and Shimura and others.


Comment: Yes, I was hoping Blasius' paper attached motives to algebraic Hecke characters in the process, but I see from this excellent paper of Harder–Schappacher that you've found that he instead uses a trick. Thanks for that paper it's quite nice.

Comment: Dear Rob H. & Junkie: It is kind of embarrassing for the field that with all of the recent activity around the F-M conjecture there isn't a place in the recent (= last 15 years) literature where the 1-dimensional case is specifically addressed and proved (even if the "proof" amounts to gathering appropriate earlier references and explaining why they are sufficient for the desired conclusion). Hmm, maybe I should put this in the Hawaii lecture notes (oy vey, just 2 more months till that's due to be done...).

Comment: Indeed BCnrd, it would be great to see the proof somewhere! And I encourage you to put it in the Hawaii notes, though that's not necessarily the first place I'd think to look for a proof of Fontaine–Mazur for GL(1)...

Good luck finishing up the notes, the preliminary version is already great!!

Comment: Peter, see http://www.math.u-psud.fr/~fargues/Motifs_abeliens.ps section 8 where you can find the references for FM conjecture for GL_1 (in particular you have to use a transcendence result in general).

Comment: Laurent, great reference -- I will print it out and take a look at it, but in the meantime a question comes to mind: do you plan to publish it somewhere, say in a journal devoted to expository articles (or elsewhere)?

Comment: Indeed, a great reference! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Laurent F.: Thanks for the very nice and very readable paper.

Comment: New link to Laurent Fargues's paper: https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~laurent.fargues/Motifs_abeliens.ps