# CM abelian variety from an algebraic Hecke character?

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties, motives, langlands-conjectures

Hi,

Given an algebraic Hecke character $\chi$ of a number field $k$ there should be a
"rank 1 CM-motive" $M$ with
$\overline Q$-coefficients such that $L(s,M) = L(s,\chi)$. This follows from the general
theory of the Taniyama group and its quotient, the Serre group. My question is if there is a simpler way of constructing the motive $M$ starting from $\chi$...

Thanks!

Comment: See Schappacher's book, Periods of Hecke characters (chapter un on Motives). http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BFb0082094

See also the thread http://mathoverflow.net/questions/33269/fontaine-mazur-for-gl-1